# Surjective function induced by bilinear pairing

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and let $V,K$ be $k$-vector spaces. If $\circ : V \times W \to k$ is a $k$-bilinear pairing we have (two) $k$-linear maps, one of them is $$\phi: V \to \text{Hom}_{k}(W,k)$$ given by $\phi(v)=\phi_v$ where $\phi_v(w)=v \circ w$. Is it true the $\phi$ is always surjective?

Comment: No. For example $\circ = 0$ ...

Answer (score 1):

No. $\phi$ being onto needs that $\dim V \ge \dim {\rm Hom}_k(W,k)$, that does not need to be true. In the finite dimensional case, this restricts to $\dim V \ge \dim W$, as for finite dimensional $W$, we have $\dim {\rm Hom}_k(W, k) = \dim W$. But even if this is true, we need some conditions of $\circ$, note that the map $\circ = 0$ is bilinear, but $\phi = 0$ is only onto iff $W = 0$.